# Яндекс карта, поставить цифру в метку

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть вот [такая карта](https://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/2pro7L4x/) со своими метками. Как поставить нумерацию меткам, чтоб выглядело [вот так](http://prntscr.com/bllytb)? Через `iconContent` не получилось и я так полагаю, что из-за того, что метка не дефолтная, версия API 2.1.

Comment: 'default#imageWithContent' — пользовательское изображение иконки с содержимым; а у вас iconLayout: 'default#image',

Comment: Супер, не знал, огромное спасибо! напиши как ответ на вопрос, я отмечу как правильный)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default#imageWithContent` — пользовательское изображение иконки с содержимым